# Customized ListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I have an external data file containing the elements `(t,x,y,px,py)` of an orbit. Here is a sample [data file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ctymf5wi3ax6ucf/orb_lp.out).

Now I want to `ListPlot` the `(x,y)` coordinates of the orbit and each `(x,y)` point to have a color according to the corresponding value of time `t` (first row).

```
data2 = data[[All, {2, 3}]];
L0 = ListPlot[data2, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, Joined -> True, 
      AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

At the right side of the plot it should be a colorbar explaining the color code (rainbow colors, red ---> small t, purple ---> high t). The colorbar should run from the minimum value of time `tmin` up to maximum `tmax` where

```
data3 = Table[data[[i, 1]], {i, 1, Length[data]}];
tmin = Min[data3];
tmax = Max[data3];
Print["t_min = ", tmin]
Print["t_max = ", tmax]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: As a start: `Graphics[Line[data[[All, {2, 3}]], VertexColors -> (ColorData["ThermometerColors"] /@ Rescale[data[[All, 1]]])]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Very good but there are some issues. (a) How to control the thickness of the line (b) how to create the colorbar? (c) use Rainbow colors with red for low values of t and purple for high values of t. Perhaps an answer incorporating these issues should be more illuminating.

Comment: @J.M. Minus one issue. I found how to control the thickness of the line.

Comment: [Not really a fan of the rainbow](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MCG.2007.323435) for scientific visualization, TBH. As for the colorbar, look up `BarLegend[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the way myself!

```
valrange = {tmin, tmax};
data[[All, 1]] = Rescale[data[[All, 1]] // N, valrange];
colfunc[x_, cf_] := ColorData[cf][1 - x[[1]]];

S0 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.005], Line[data[[All, {2, 3}]], 
VertexColors -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - #] & /@ 
   Rescale[data[[All, 1]]])]}];
```

Now we have to build a custom colorbar

```
Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := 
DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{None, "t"}, {None, None}}, 
RotateLabel -> False, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20, Plain], 
ColorFunction -> colorFunction]
```

and finally combine the `Graphics` with the custom colorbar

```
plot = With[{opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 500}}, cf = "Rainbow"}, 
       Row[{Show[{S0}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
       FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
       LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
       AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> 55, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
       PlotRangePadding -> 0, AspectRatio -> 1, 
       ImagePadding -> {{80, 10}, {60, 40}}, opts], 
       Show[colorbar[valrange, ColorData[cf][1 - #] &], 
       ImagePadding -> {{10, 60}, {60, 40}}, opts]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Well done, you! A tiny tip: `ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - #] &` is better done as `ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Here's your `colorbar` slightly improved: `colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, (max - min)/10}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20, Plain], ColorFunction -> colorFunction, FrameLabel -> {{None, Rotate["t", -90 °]}, {None, None}}, FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, PlotRangePadding -> None]` I take it you're not on the newest version to be able to use `BarLegend[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Why `(max - min)/10` is better? This is the only difference I observe. I have v10.2 of MMA in my Win 7 PC. What would be the equivalent of `BarLegent`?

Comment: Only because I set `AspectRatio -> Automatic`. 10.2 should have `BarLegend[]`; why not use that instead of `colorbar[]`?

Answer (score 5):

```
opts1 = Hue /@ (data[[All, 1]]/10) (*Color*)
opts2 = Thickness[(1 + #)/700] & /@ data[[All, 1]] (*Thickness*)

Row[{Graphics[Flatten[Riffle[Line /@ Partition[data[[All, {2, 3}]], 2, 1],
Transpose[{opts1, opts2}]]], Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300], 
BarLegend[{Hue, {Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want Rainbow colors instead of Hue? Also is it possible the colorbar to have the same height as the square of the plot?

Comment: Replace `Hue /@ (data[[All, 1]]/10)` by `ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ (data[[All, 1]]/10)` and in the legend `Hue` by `ColorData["Rainbow"]`